# how to get retirement of this month by date of birth

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I want to show retirement of current month by date of birth. I have a column **dob** (format is 1960-12-21). Now I have to calculate 60 years from **dob** by current month. If current month is **October 2020** and date of birth is **1960-09-21** then records should be fetch. Today's date doesn't matter. But if month is **September 2020 OR November 2020** then data should not show.

Records should be fetch by current month, if current month completes 60 years.

**Means results should be:**

Retirement of this month is: abc,xyz etc.

I tried, but I am not getting my results:

Controller is:

```
 public function index()
    {
        $retirement = User::select('name','dob')->get();
        foreach($retirement as $retirement)
        {
            echo Carbon::parse($retirement->dob)->age;
          
        }
    }
```

It shows years only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `whereMonth()` and `whereYear()` to find the current month and where the year is 60 years ago. You can achieve this by getting `now()` and then accessing the `month` and `year` properties respectively.

```php
$retirement = User::whereMonth('dob', now()->month)
                  ->whereYear('dob', now()->subYears(60)->year)
                  ->get();
```

Comment: Sorry, your solution is perfect. I tested with wrong data.